# Mongodb query doesn't return any results

Tags: mongodb

I have objects similar to this one in a Mongo database :

```
{
  "_id": "56c9dd59fe418a1c0558e466",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures/149373"
    },
    "soccerseason": {
      "href": "api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/405"
    },
    "homeTeam": {
      "href": "api.football-data.org/v1/teams/559"
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "href": "api.football-data.org/v1/teams/18"
    }
  },
  "date": "2015-09-15T18:45:00Z",
  "status": "FINISHED",
  "matchday": 1,
  "homeTeamName": "Sevilla FC",
  "awayTeamName": "Bor. Mönchengladbach",
  "result": {
    "goalsHomeTeam": 3,
    "goalsAwayTeam": 0
  }
}
```

But when I use

> collection.find({"_links": {"soccerseason": {"href" : "api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/405"}}})

I don't get any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to query embedded documents:

```
db.collection.find({"_links.soccerseason.href": "api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/405"})
```